# UICollectionview custom layout: some indexes have more visible cells than others?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I'm facing a weird issue that I can't seem to figure out or find anything about online.

So I'm trying to replicate the Shazam discover UI with a `UICollectionView` and a custom `UICollectionViewFlowlayout`.

So far everything is working pretty well, but **when adding the "card stack" effect I (or rather the person who was implementing it) noticed there seems to be a weird issue where on some occasions (or rather, when specific indexes are visible, in the example it's row 5, 9) there will be 4 visible cells instead of 3.** My guess would be that this has something to do with cell reuse, but I'm not sure why it's doing this. I looked into the individual cell dimensions and they all seem to be the same so it's not that cells are just sized differently.

Does anyone have an idea as to why this could be happening? Any help or suggestions are really appreciated.

I'll add a code snippet of the custom flowlayout and screenshots below. 
You can [download the full project here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8cd241hbr0e8zsr/VerticalCardSwiper.zip?dl=0), or alternatively, check out [the PR on Github](https://github.com/JoniVR/VerticalCardSwiper/pull/14).

Here's a visual comparison:

[image]
[image]

Source code of the custom flowlayout:

```
import UIKit

/// Custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` that provides the flowlayout information like paging and `CardCell` movements.
internal class VerticalCardSwiperFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    /// This property sets the amount of scaling for the first item.
    internal var firstItemTransform: CGFloat?
    /// This property enables paging per card. The default value is true.
    internal var isPagingEnabled: Bool = true
    /// Stores the height of a CardCell.
    internal var cellHeight: CGFloat!

    internal override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()

        assert(collectionView!.numberOfSections == 1, "Number of sections should always be 1.")
        assert(collectionView!.isPagingEnabled == false, "Paging on the collectionview itself should never be enabled. To enable cell paging, use the isPagingEnabled property of the VerticalCardSwiperFlowLayout instead.")
    }

    internal override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        let items = NSMutableArray (array: super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)!, copyItems: true)

        items.enumerateObjects(using: { (object, index, stop) -> Void in
            let attributes = object as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes

            self.updateCellAttributes(attributes)
        })

        return items as? [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]
    }

    // We invalidate the layout when a "bounds change" happens, for example when we scale the top cell. This forces a layout update on the flowlayout.
    internal override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    // Cell paging
    internal override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {

        // If the property `isPagingEnabled` is set to false, we don't enable paging and thus return the current contentoffset.
        guard isPagingEnabled else {
            let latestOffset = super.targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset: proposedContentOffset, withScrollingVelocity: velocity)
            return latestOffset
        }

        // Page height used for estimating and calculating paging.
        let pageHeight = cellHeight + self.minimumLineSpacing

        // Make an estimation of the current page position.
        let approximatePage = self.collectionView!.contentOffset.y/pageHeight

        // Determine the current page based on velocity.
        let currentPage = (velocity.y < 0.0) ? floor(approximatePage) : ceil(approximatePage)

        // Create custom flickVelocity.
        let flickVelocity = velocity.y * 0.4

        // Check how many pages the user flicked, if <= 1 then flickedPages should return 0.
        let flickedPages = (abs(round(flickVelocity)) <= 1) ? 0 : round(flickVelocity)

        // Calculate newVerticalOffset.
        let newVerticalOffset = ((currentPage + flickedPages) * pageHeight) - self.collectionView!.contentInset.top

        return CGPoint(x: proposedContentOffset.x, y: newVerticalOffset)
    }

    internal override func finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItem(at itemIndexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {

        // make sure the zIndex of the next card is higher than the one we're swiping away.
        let nextIndexPath = IndexPath(row: itemIndexPath.row + 1, section: itemIndexPath.section)
        let nextAttr = self.layoutAttributesForItem(at: nextIndexPath)
        nextAttr?.zIndex = nextIndexPath.row

        // attributes for swiping card away
        let attr = self.layoutAttributesForItem(at: itemIndexPath)

        return attr
    }

    /**
     Updates the attributes.
     Here manipulate the zIndex of the cards here, calculate the positions and do the animations.
     - parameter attributes: The attributes we're updating.
     */
    fileprivate func updateCellAttributes(_ attributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
        let minY = collectionView!.bounds.minY + collectionView!.contentInset.top
        let maxY = attributes.frame.origin.y

        let finalY = max(minY, maxY)
        var origin = attributes.frame.origin
        let deltaY = (finalY - origin.y) / attributes.frame.height
        let translationScale = CGFloat((attributes.zIndex + 1) * 10)

        // create stacked effect (cards visible at bottom
        if let itemTransform = firstItemTransform {
            let scale = 1 - deltaY * itemTransform
            var t = CGAffineTransform.identity
            t = t.scaledBy(x: scale, y: 1)
            t = t.translatedBy(x: 0, y: (translationScale + deltaY * translationScale))

            attributes.transform = t
        }

        origin.x = (self.collectionView?.frame.width)! / 2 - attributes.frame.width / 2 - (self.collectionView?.contentInset.left)!
        origin.y = finalY
        attributes.frame = CGRect(origin: origin, size: attributes.frame.size)
        attributes.zIndex = attributes.indexPath.row
    }
}
```

**edit 1:** Just as an extra clarification, the final end result should make it look something like this:

[image]

**edit 2:** 
Seems to be happening every 4-5 cards you scroll from my testing.

Comment: In `layoutAttributesForElements(in:)` print `items` before the `return`. Check if the frames are correct. Something like: `items.forEach({print("IndexPath:\($0.indexPath) frame: \($0.frame)})` or something like that. Check the frames, maybe one didn't updated correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is on how you defined `frame.origin.y` for each attribute. More specifically the value you hold in `minY` and determines how many of the cells you're keeping on screen. (I will edit this answer and explain more later but for now, try replacing the following code)

```
var minY = collectionView!.bounds.minY + collectionView!.contentInset.top
let maxY = attributes.frame.origin.y

if minY > attributes.frame.origin.y + attributes.bounds.height + minimumLineSpacing + collectionView!.contentInset.top {
   minY = 0
}
```

Comment: That did it, what a simple solution, I'm very eager to hear the explanation! Thank you so much!

Comment: Any chance you could give me that explanation you promised? I'm not exactly seeing how it was going wrong and it could provide me with some useful insight.

Comment: @JoniVR I'm very sorry I forgot about this. I'll hopefully find some time over the weekend and get back to you

Answer (score 2):

You have a layout that inherits from flow layout.  You overrode `layoutAttributesForElements(in rect:)` where you take all the elements from `super.layoutAttributesForElements` and then for each one modify the properties in the method `updateCellAttributes`.

This is generally a good way to make a subclass of a flow layout.  The `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` is doing most of the hard work - figuring out where each element should be, which elements are in the rect, what their basically attributes are, how they should be padded, etc, and you can just modify a few properties after the "hard" work is done.  This works fine when you are adding a rotation or opacity or some other feature that does not change the location of the item.

You get into trouble when you change the items frame with `updateCellAttributes`.  Then you can have a situation when you have a cell that would not have appeared in the frame at all for the regular flow layout, but now SHOULD appear because of your modification.  So the attribute is not being returned AT ALL by super.layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) so they don't show up at all.  You can also have the opposite problem that cells that should not be in the frame at all are in the view but transformed in a way that cannot be seen by the user.

You haven't explained enough of what effect you are trying to do and why you think inheriting from UIFlowLayout is correct for me to be able to specifically help you.  But I hope that I have given you enough information that you can find the problem on your own.

Comment: Hi, first of all, thanks for your answer, it provides some useful insight. I'll try playing around with that in mind.
The effect I'm trying to achieve is the same as the shazam discover effect. A card stack where scrolling slides the card down the stack and previous cards are visible at the bottom, like in the image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/89Rko.jpg